# Missing project.app file in xcode

Tags: xcode

I have an xcode project for iOS and I suddently noticed that my project file project.app is unavailable...? How could I recreate this? Is it necessary to have this file? I'm using latest XCode 5.
[image]

Comment: you probably just cleaned your project or something. just rebuild the app.

Comment: Build works fine, but file is still not available. I clicked 'Clean' and now the file is displayed in red. Then I click 'Build' and the application runs fine but project.app is still not available. Is this file needed?